# Return list<integer> object with largest size

Tags: java, list, hash

How do i return the the object with the largest length?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer>list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer>list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    HashSet<List<Integer>> hash = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();

    list.add(2);
    list1.add(3); 
    list1.add(4);
    hash.add(list);
    hash.add(list1);
}

public static List<Integer> meth(HashSet<List<Integer>> hash){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(hash.isEmpty()){
        return list;
    }
    else{
        for(List<Integer> value : hash){
            // probably something here?
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

I know that list1 is larger than list but how would I get java to do this? I want it to return the largest list in a `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static List<Integer> meth(HashSet<List<Integer>> hash){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(List<Integer> value : hash){
        if(value.size() > list.size()) {
            list = value;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

- Please note you can omit your if-else-construct.
- This solution cannot distinguish whether the longest list in the hash set was of length zero, or the hash set was empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8, you can use the new [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

```
public static List<Integer> meth(HashSet<List<Integer>> hash){
    return hash.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Collection::size))
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
}
```

Otherwise, what you can do is keep track of the largest list as you iterate.

```
List<Integer> largest = Collections.emptyList();

for (List<Integer> value : hash) {
    if (value.size() > largest.size()) {
        largest = value;
    }
}

return largest;
```

Comment: You could also do `.max(Comparator.comparingInt(Collection::size))` (+1)

Answer (score 0):

you can add following instead your comment `// probably something here?`

```
if (value.size() > list.size())
    list = value;
```

Comment: Yup thanks, thats what i wanted! So simple but i didn't see it. CHeers